# problems with the return value of fscanf in c

Tags: c, return-value, scanf

I'm sorry to do this kind of question (because there is so much on internet about that) but I have to ask this:

The exercise involve reading from a file with a list of students (a record contains: name, surname and serial number). I've already created the document and consist of 13 lines, but when I write on terminal `./a.out`, the output is a list of 13 lines of this type: `(null) (null) (null)`

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define EOF (-1)
#define BUF 100

typedef struct stud{
    char *surname;
    char *name;
    char *serial;
} student;

int main(void){
    FILE *fd;
    int n = BUF;
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int ret;
    char *s = malloc(BUF * sizeof(char));
    if((fd = fopen("registry_office_students.txt","r")) == NULL){
        perror("error opening file");
        return -1;
    }
    while(fgets(s,n,fd)!=NULL){
        k++;
    }
    student *a = malloc(k*sizeof(student));
    rewind(fd);
    ret = fscanf(fd, "%s, %s, %s", a[i].surname, a[i].name, a[i].serial);
    while(fscanf(fd, "%s, %s, %s", a[i].surname, a[i].name, a[i].serial) == ret){
        i++; 
    }
    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        printf("%s, %s, %s \n", a[i].surname, a[i].name, a[i].serial);
    }
    fclose(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize again and hope for a proper response, Thanks.

Comment: Did you carefully read several times the documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html)? What is the problem?

Comment: @JeroenvanderHooft The code above is valid. It allows Carmine to refer to the struct as `struct stud` or as `student`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fscanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) with `%s` won't allocate any memory for a string. That string should already exist.

At least, replace

```
    ret = fscanf(fd, "%s, %s, %s", 
                 a[i].surname, a[i].name, a[i].serial);
```

with something like

```
   {
      char surname[48];
      char name[64];
      char serial[32];
      memset (surname, 0, sizeof(surname));
      memset (name, 0, sizeof(name));
      memset (serial, 0, sizeof(serial));
      memset (a+i, 0, sizeof(struct stud));
      ret = fscanf(fd, "%47s, %63s, %31s", surname, name, serial);
      if (ret==3) {
         a[i].surname = strdup(surname);
         if (!a[i].surname) 
           { perror("strdup surname"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
         a[i].name = strdup(name);
         if (!a[i].name) 
           { perror("strdup name"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
         a[i].serial = strdup(serial);
         if (!a[i].serial) 
           { perror("strdup serial"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
      }
   }
```

Notice that I am clearing memory before reading it. I am explicitly giving size of strings in format of `fscanf`. I am duplicating with a *tested* `strdup` the read strings into heap.

Actually, I believe your approach could be wrong. You might decide that each student should be on a single line, which you would read with [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and parse with [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (maybe `%n` would be useful!) or maybe `strtok`  (or "manually" using `isalpha`)

Please, read more material about C programming, then compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`), learn to use the debugger (`gdb`) and the memory leak detector ([valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you never allocate memory for the strings stored inside your structs. I.e. your `fscanf` attempts to read data into buffers that don't exist.

Secondly, your reading code reads data into `a[0]` twice. I.e. the first `fscanf` will read the first record in `a[0]` and then the next `fscanf` will read the next record into `a[0]` again, overriding what was read previously. Why? Was that your intent (like skipping a table header or something like that)?

Thirdly, your counting code (`fgets`) is not the same as your reading code (`fscanf`). If the reading code fails prematurely for `fscanf`-specific reason, you will read less than `k` records. Yet your printing code prints all `k` of them unconditionally. (What if your reading code failed immediately due to some error in `fscanf` format? In that case you never read anything.)

Fourthly, each call to `fgets` in your counting code is limited by `100` characters or by a newline (that's how `fgets` works). This is completely non-synchronized with how `fscanf` works, which is not limited by anything in your case. This means that the number of records seen by the counting code might easily end up different (greater) than the number of records seen by the reading code.